# exporting an imported function or serial inheritance of function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

How to export `function fx(pm)` defined in file `c.js` to file `a.js` thru serial inheritance from    c.js to b.js and then from b.js to a.js?

file c.js

```
 export.fx = function(pm) {
 //code
 return Result
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//c.js is already mentioned above.

in b.js

```
var c = require('./c');
exports.fn=c.fun;
```

now in a.js

```
var b = require('./b');
var Result = b.fn(pm);
```